# My timer keeps counting down, onFinish method didn't work. [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to stop Counter when time is over. But in my situation when time is over, timer restart and counting again. I don't know why my onFinish method doesn't work good. Thanks for all support.

```
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished
                updateCountDownText()
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                isRunning = false
                isStartingAlarm = true
                startPauseButton.text = "Start"
                startPauseButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                resetButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                alarmSound.start()
            }
        }.start()
```

Comment: Please share more of your code, specifically all of the functions not shown. Some questions for you to answer in your post (edits): Why are you changing the value of `timeLeftInMillis` in `onTick`? Why not pass `millisUntilFinished` to `updateCountDownText`? How are `isRunning` and `isStartingAlarm` used? Also, there's no point in changing the text of a view that you are setting to INVISIBLE. Did you mean to put that elsewhere?

Comment: Here I put all code i wrote. Let's check: https://pastebin.com/2CpqVC74

Comment: It looks like my onFinish method is not getting called